# regular expression double entries in xml filtering

Tags: regex, xml

I am working with XML files and try to find a solution which I mean seems simple, but the syntax is hard to find.

```html
<data>
  <hauptknoten>
    <zweiterknoten>
      <subknoten3>sub3textTagInput</subknoten3>
    </zweiterknoten>
    <zweiterknoten>
      <subknoten4>sub4textTagInput</subknoten4>
    </zweiterknoten>
  </hauptknoten>
</data>
```

As we see in the middle of the XML file there is

```
</zweiterknoten>
<zweiterknoten>
```

I tried `var pattern:RegExp =/\w+(<\/(\w+)(>))(<(\w+)(>))/`
also the  `var pattern:RegExp = (?:<\/(\w+)(>))(<(\w+)(>))*?`
but these don't match.

I am pretty sure there is a solution, can anyone assist me?

Comment: Why do you want to tackle this task with an inadequate tool ? Think of xml comments or CDATA section containing the string you want to match. FWIW, `/<\/zweiterknoten>[^<]*<zweiterknoten>/`does the trick but it is **not recommended**.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, @Glowhollow, feel free to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

As a standard caveat, you cannot *parse* hierarchically structured data (such as XML or HTML) with a regex.  That's not to say that you can't do useful things with regex, but it is not possible to fully parse it in a robust way.

To find what you're looking for (an end tag, followed by whitespace, followed by a matching open tag), you can use this:

```
/<\/(\w+)>\s*<\1>/g
```

The tag name is captured by the first group, and then matched again at the end (`\1`).

If you're looking to only find that *specific* element, just replace the `\w+`:

```
/<\/(zweiterknoten)>\s*<\1>/g
```